# Proportional odds assumption for grouped data with known thresholds

Tags: r, assumptions, ordered-logit

I have a question regarding ordinal logit model. My dependent variable, y, is grouped by known thresholds. For example, 1, 2 and 3 define income less than $ 9,999, income between 10000-39,999, and income greater than or equal 40,000, respectively.

After I employed Harrell's graphical method (plot.xmean.ordinaly in rms package of R) to validate the proportional odds assumption, I concluded that the proportionality assumption is violated.

Here are my questions:

1. Since the y is grouped by known thresholds, should the proportional odds assumption be complied?
2. If the proportional ordinal logit model is not an ideal approach here, can I use the generalized ordinal model instead?